# Lenovo Thinkpad x1 carbon 7th Gen cannot use fingerprint reader

Tags: 19.10, thinkpad

Any solution for fingerprint scanner to work ubuntu 19.10 ? :(((

Answer (score 1):

Updating firmware as described in [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)#Fingerprint_sensor) helped me on 20.04:

```
# fwupdmgr refresh
# fwupdmgr get-updates
# fwupdmgr update
```

After restart I was able to set fingerprint via `Settings -> User -> Fingerprint Login`

I think this should also work on 19.10

Comment: I didn't even need to restart, the "Fingerprint Login" menu option was there after I ran the update and reopened the settings app.